# Tables inside table

Tags: tables

I would like to write latex code for getting a table as that appears in image.

[image]d you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Where you stuck in your effort? In your  outer able you should use the `m` column type defined in the `array` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure I mistyped some entries but to first approximation you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
$\begin{array}{|c|cc|cc|}
\hline
C_2 & E & C_2 & E & C_2\\
\hline
A & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
B & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
\hline
A & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
B & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
~\times~
\begin{array}{|c|cc|}
\hline
C_s & E & \sigma\\
\hline
A' & 1 & 1\\
A'' & 1 & -1\\
\hline
\end{array}
~=~
\begin{array}{|c|cc|cc|}
\hline
C_{2\nu} & E & C_2 & \sigma & \sigma_\nu'\\
\hline
A_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
B_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
\hline
A_2 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
B_2 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's I want it